# How to wait, in JAVASCRIPT, for the return value of a first function?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise, return

I've. simple `JS` code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const location = new AWS.Location({ region: "us-east-1" });


async function calculateCoordinates(INDEX_NAME, ADDRESS_BLOCK) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var params = {
      IndexName: INDEX_NAME,
      Text: ADDRESS_BLOCK,
    };

    location.searchPlaceIndexForText(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var coordinates = [];
        coordinates.push(data.Summary.ResultBBox[0]);
        coordinates.push(data.Summary.ResultBBox[1]);
        resolve(coordinates);
      }
    });
  });
}

async function extractCountry(INDEX_NAME, LAT, LON) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var params = {
      IndexName: INDEX_NAME,
      Position: [LAT, LON],
  };
  location.searchPlaceIndexForPosition(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
          reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(data.Results[0].Place.Country);
      }
  });
});

}
```

As you can see, I've two functions: `calculateCoordinates`, and `extractCountry`. `calculateCoordinates` returns an array `coordinates`. The array contains two value. This two value should be the input value of `extractCountry` (`lat` = `coordinates[0]` and `lon` = `coordinates[1]`). So, I need to say: **execute `calculateCoordinates`, wait until the return value is ready, and then put this return value into `extractCordinates`**. How to do it?

```
calculateCoordinates('INDICEDIPOSIZIONE', 'ROMA')
  .then(coordinates => {
    console.log('Coordinates:', coordinates);



    extractCountry('INDICEDIPOSIZIONE', coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
  .then(country => {
    console.log('Country:', country);
    
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
    
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

But country is undefined, because I suppose the second function is executed until the first one has finished

Comment: Neither of those functions need to be `async`. They have no `await`, and they're both returning promises.

Comment: `promises.reduce((p,c) => p.then(v => (doSomethingSyncWith(v), c)).catch(handleError);`

Comment: "*I suppose the second function is executed until the first one has finished*" - no, they execute one after the other, just as you expect. If `country` is `undefined`, that's because `data.Results[0].Place.Country` is `undefined`. Debug the response you're getting.